# Passing data up through nested functions in .js

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-apps-script

Coding beginner here. I've got a page-js script below which when a dropdown is changed it triggers function getDrawNumOne, which in turn runs a function and retrieves two pieces of data from a GoogleSheet (drawNumReturnOne[0] & [1]). I want to pass the returned drawNumReturnOne[1] up through getDrawOneNum and then on into doStuff for use there - but am struggling on how to do this in a slick way, given I cannot call variables outside of their function scope. Do I need multiple returns up through the function stack or is there another, better way? All advice gratefully accepted, thanks.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
document.getElementById("m_p1").addEventListener("onchange",getDrawNumOne);
   
function doStuff(){    
   var userInfo ={};
   userInfo.m_p1 = document.getElementById("m_p1").value;
   userInfo.m_s1 = ######;
   google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
    
   }
   
function getDrawNumOne(){
var drawNumOne = document.getElementById("m_p1").value;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateDrawNumOne).getDrawNo(drawNumOne); 
   
}
function updateDrawNumOne(drawNumReturnOne){
   document.getElementById("draw1").value = drawNumReturnOne[0];
   ###### = drawNumReturnOne[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, as a simple method, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
let sample = ""; // Added

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
document.getElementById("m_p1").addEventListener("change", getDrawNumOne); // Modified

function doStuff() {
  var userInfo = {};
  userInfo.m_p1 = document.getElementById("m_p1").value;
  userInfo.m_s1 = sample; // Modified
  google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
}

function getDrawNumOne() {
  var drawNumOne = document.getElementById("m_p1").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateDrawNumOne).getDrawNo(drawNumOne);
}

function updateDrawNumOne(drawNumReturnOne) {
  document.getElementById("draw1").value = drawNumReturnOne[0];
  sample = drawNumReturnOne[1]; // Modified
}
```

- As another modification point, I thought that in your script, `onchange` of `document.getElementById("m_p1").addEventListener("onchange",getDrawNumOne);` is `change`. But, if your situation can be used as `onchange`, please use it.